# Не обновляется атрибут модели react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

у меня есть модель User с атрибутом name

```
export default class User {
    private name: string;
}
```

Также есть геттеры и сеттеры у класса.
Есть компонент, которому в пропсах передается user

```
interface FrameProps {
    user: User;
}
interface FrameState {
}
export default class Frame extends React.Component<FrameProps, FrameState> {
    constructor(props: FrameProps) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        let me = this;
        return (
            <div style={{marginTop: 180, display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center"}}>
                <h1>{me.props.user.name.toString()}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

в App.tsx передаю как

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Frame user={new User()}></Frame>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при обновлении имени в модели User, он не обновляется во Frame. И выводится всегда начально введенное имя, как я поняла, из-за того, что меняются только пропсы, но не атрибуты пропса. Как это можно изменить? Передавать нужно именно юзера.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге я сама нашла решение, нужно изменить класс Frame так:

{me.props.user.name.toString()}

Comment: так в вопросе точно такой же код